# Unable to set iOS - iPhone in App Center Listed Platforms

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-center, facebook-app-settings

I tried in every way, I consulted a lot of post on StackOverflow, but no one gave me the right solution! I can not enable iOS - iPhone App Center Listed Platforms Facebook. I have everything complete in every detail (the app is on the App Store, but I uploaded the binary myApp.ipa). iPhone Store ID is blank because my App is in review (iTunes Connect), but I repeat, I uploaded my app myapp.ipa !
Please help me

[image]

Comment: If it is like mine, the [?] will say that it is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set '0' on iPhone Store ID?

Comment: Yes, but it reset again to blank

Answer (score 0):

All of your required settings must be set, but they don't validate to tell you exactly what is missing. Use the guide at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/tutorial

Some commonly missed items are the iPhone Store ID and urls such as the privacy policy URL, but step through that entire guide to see what is missing.